# Trouble with operator [] in Debug Window VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, debugging, operators

I have a c++ class of matrices with only one field:

```
template <class T>
class matrix {
private:
    std::vector < std::vector <T>> elements;
public:
    ...
}
```

Also I have overdriven operator []:

```
    std::vector <T>& operator[] (int index) {
        return elements[index];
    }
    const std::vector <T>& operator[] (int index) const {
        return elements[index];
    }
```

And I can use it in code

```
    matrix <double> A(5,5);
    A[1][3] = 5;
```

But I can't add such expressions to debug window. I add A[2] or A[2][3] and get `no operator "[]" corresponding to these operands`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you can. You have to view elements manually. They have better representation for STL types but never heard how to improve it for custom types. There could be plugins though.

Comment: @ALX23z: [Natvis - Native Visualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Is the workaround `A.elements[2][3]` acceptable? The debugger ignores `private:`.

Comment: @MSalters it will surely work, I was just trying to figure out how to do it this way

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is solved, I would appreciate it if you could  write it as an answer and mark it. This will be beneficial to other community.